# Alternate world travel finds church with women priests

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

I read a story in the 1990s (I think) in Asimov's (almost sure) in which travel between a limited (half dozen) alternate worlds had become possible; relations between those worlds were peaceful.  Then a new world was discovered, and a historian/priest visited a church there to study the differences in practices, and discovered that communion involved menstrual blood of women priests.  The main character is convinced that this is an ancient heresy that had been suppressed in the other worlds, and anticipates a war of extermination against the new world.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

["From Whom All Blessings Flow"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41716), a novelette by [Stephen Dedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Dedman), first published in [*Asimov's Science Fiction*, April 1995](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57235+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v19n04-n05_1995-04/page/n169/mode/2up?view=theater).

Travel between alternate worlds has become possible:

> Kaarina Schroeder, the inventor of the Bifrost Bridge, was born in what later became known as World One, which was fine as long as the only other World discovered had a population of a few million humans and trillions of mutated rats. The next World contacted, however, was technologically advanced enough to build their end of a Bifrost Bridge, and they refused to accept the title of World Three. After a few months of (occasionally acrimonious) discussion, World One became World Green, and World Three, World Blue, largely because of the background colors of their respective U.N. flags. Their histories had diverged sharply in 1906, when the English Revolution didn’t happen in World Blue—mostly because some of the ringleaders were already dead, or not in London. Historians had found minor divergences as far back as 1879, and some joked about the *real* divergence points being lost in prehistory.
>
> World Two became World Cyan, but none of the rats were heard to complain—at least, not to the historians. Then there was World Azure, where Robert Kennedy had been *fatally* shot; and World Indigo, where there hadn't been a Great Fire of London; and then another cold ruin which was christened World Grey and quickly abandoned . . . and then, a world so different from World Green that none of their living languages were recognizable, which became known on the other Worlds as World Red.

World Red is the one with priestesses:

> "Their 'Mark' is more likely 'Mary,' Monsignor." said Anagnostakos, gently. "Matthew, Martha; Luke, Lucy; John, Joan. Their 'Old Testament' seems to be Sumerian or Babylonian—'
>
> "But they believe in Christ," replied Whately. "Their interpreter wears a crucifix, almost identical to mine, and I've seen her cross herself. The
> crucifixion picture in their Bible is the same as ours, even down to the
> woman kneeling before the cross, and the Last Supper—"
>
> "Their interpreter is a priestess. Their 'pope' is a woman, the 'World
> Mother.' How long has the Catholic Church in World Blue been ordaining
> women? Over here, it's been less than fifty years.

Communion as you described it:

> Finally, a number of the congregation moved to the railing at the head of the church, and knelt before it—some with hands behind their backs, some with hands clasped in prayer, and Whately's eyes filled with tears of joy. Dr. Esa, wearing a burgundy-colored kimono-like robe, stepped toward them. "Take and eat it," translated Anagnostakos, in a murmur, "This is my body. Drink; this is my blood, poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins." Then, as the offWorlders watched, Dr. Esa opened the divided skirt of her robe, and guided a boy's face toward her groin. Then she moved over to the girl beside him, and repeated the gesture.
>
> The boy, feeling the pressure of Whately's stare, turned around. Whately saw blood on his lips, and screamed.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought (and should have written) that there was a title using wordplay.